# How to aggregate two largest values per group in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I was going through this link: [Return top N largest values per group using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468897/return-top-n-largest-values-per-group-using-pandas)

and found multiple ways to find the topN values per group.

However, I prefer dictionary method with agg function and would like to know if it is possible to get the equivalent of the dictionary method for the following problem?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,   1,   1,   2,   2],
                   'B': [1,   1,   2,   2,   1],
                   'C': [10,  20,  30,  40,  50],
                   'D': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y']})
print(df)
   A  B   C  D
0  1  1  10  X
1  1  1  20  Y
2  1  2  30  X
3  2  2  40  Y
4  2  1  50  Y
```

## I can do this:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['A'])['C'].nlargest(2).droplevel(-1).reset_index()
print(df1)
   A   C
0  1  30
1  1  20
2  2  50
3  2  40

# also this
df1 = df.sort_values('C', ascending=False).groupby('A', sort=False).head(2)
print(df1)

# also this
df.set_index('C').groupby('A')['B'].nlargest(2).reset_index()
```

## Required

```
df.groupby('A',as_index=False).agg(
    {'C': lambda ser: ser.nlargest(2)  # something like this
    })
```

Is it possible to use the dictionary here?

Comment: What's the reason you want to use a dictionary method perse?

Comment: @Erfan, to be consistent and use agg.{dict} for all the groupby cases. Pandas has so many methods to do the same operation, it is good habit to stick to one paradigm and try to follow it everywhere whenever possible. (For example, replace all use of pivot,pivot table,melt etc  with groupby and only use groupby everywhere.)

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to be honest, you should use the right method for the right usecase. Not use one method for each case because it's "consistent".

Comment: @Erfan I partially agree with you. `groupby.agg(dict)` looks easier to read and also cross-platform (eg. similar in PySpark and R). I am exploring the ways to do everything using only one method. Its hard to remember so many methods. Its good to know many alternatives but stick to one.

Comment: Two comments on this. First of all, `agg` means `aggregate` which means your results should be aggregated. Since you're not aggregating results here, makes it kind of hard to use `agg`. Second, `groupby.agg(dict)` [has been _deprecated_ as of 0.25.1 onwards](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling). So, since you have strong considerations on consistency of your code design, it makes sense to evaluate whether this is a good pattern to stick to.

Comment: Finally, there's a big performance effect on calling `groupby.agg(some_func)` and `groupby.some_func` directly. If you have an implementation provided by the`GroupBy` object, such as `GroupBy.nlargest`, always make a preference for it. It'll be way faster than using `agg` or `apply` and calling the same function for the `pd.Series` passed as argument in your lambda function.

Comment: @rafaelc Thanks for the heads up that pandas is deprecationg `agg(dict)`, It looks like I need to change paradigm from `df.groupby('A').agg(dict)` to `df.groupby('A').agg(list_of_list)` or simpy `df.groupby('A')[agg_cols].method()`. Not so happy but have to follow the trend.

Comment: It's more subtle than that. aggregating a `DataFrame.GroupBy` with a dictionary is fine and **not** deprecated. Aggregating a `Series.GroupBy` with a dictionary is deprecated. (At that point you only have a single column so really why are you using a dictionary?)  See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html#deprecate-groupby-agg-with-a-dictionary-when-renaming. `.agg(dict_of_dict)` is always bad and is deprecated regardless.

Comment: @rafaelc to be fair, `Series.groupby().agg(dict)` is deprecated. `DataFrame.groupby().agg(dict)` is something else and still valid.

Comment: @ALollz I used to use `Series.groupby().agg(dict)` for renaming purpose, e.g. `{'minimal':'min', 'total':'sum'}`. But `**kwargs` is the way now.

Comment: Good insight guys, I mistook the `series` and `dataframe` deprecations :}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a dictionary like *A: 2 top values from C*,
you can run:

```
df.groupby(['A'])['C'].apply(lambda x:
    x.nlargest(2).tolist()).to_dict()
```

For your DataFrame, the result is:

```
{1: [30, 20], 2: [50, 40]}
```